# How can I limit the number of HTTP connections in OpenLiberty?

Tags: open-liberty

I want to limit the number of HTTP connections for web applications on OpenLiberty. Which parameters should I change to do this? I'm looking at the docs, should I change maxConcurrentStreams in HTTPOption or maxThread in executer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't an existing property to specifically limit HTTP connections, so I'd recommend using `maxOpenConnections`, which is a `tcpOptions` configuration[1]. That property allows you to restrict the number of open connections for a TCP endpoint. The default value is `128000`.

`maxConcurrentStreams` applies specifically to HTTP/2 the number of *streams* that are allowed per HTTP/2 (TCP) connection, and `maxThread` won't directly accomplish what you want.

[1] https://openliberty.io/docs/21.0.0.2/reference/config/httpEndpoint.html#tcpOptions